# Running function again after route change in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, routes

So I have a main controller and two others:

```
calculatorApp.controller('companybController', function($scope, $http) {
  //define the hardware data
  $scope.customs.prodoc = 'companyb';
});

calculatorApp.controller('companyaController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.customs.prodoc = 'companya';
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
calculatorApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.customs = {
    prodoc : ''
  };
});
```

But when switching routes - this works: `{{customs.prodoc}}`, but it seems the function that uses it does not run again when the new view is loaded - causing the app to use the old values.

How do I run the function that uses the changing `$scope.customs.prodoc` again once the view has been changed?

Here's the function that uses it - I had it in `mainController` but not sure it belongs there.

```
$http.get($scope.customs.prodoc+'/products.json').success(function(thisdata) {
        $scope.products = []
        angular.forEach(thisdata, function(product) {
            $scope.products.push(product);
        });
        console.log($scope.products);
    });

$scope.change = function() {
// Suggest product
        $scope.suggested = {}
        var length = ($scope.products).length;
        for(i=0; i<length; i++){
            if($scope.products[i].CAMERA_MAX>=$scope.totals.cameras){
                $scope.suggested = $scope.products[i];
                break;
            }else{

            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Where is the function that uses it? show the code

Comment: Are you sure that the controller is executed? Can you post a more complete example?

Comment: @DavideIcardi I'm sure the controller is executed because I can use the variable on its own (and it shows the new variable from the current controller.) But the functions that use that variable don't run again. Which is what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @IlanFrumer Hi again, Ilan! I posted more code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use $routeChangeSuccess to do what you are talking about

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function($currentRoute, $previousRoute) {
    $scope.customs.prodoc = $scope.routeParams.prodoc;
});
```

Comment: Cool - where would I put this, though? In the calculatorApp.config?

Comment: Thank you - this worked perfectly once I plugged it into the two controllers and ran `$scope.change()`

Comment: @itamar you just need to put it in the destination controller.